# GPIO Button Input not triggered in Python

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio

I have recently bought a Raspberry Pi 3B, for a project where I require a program to recognize a pressed button and do something after that. It seems a common and pretty easy task for a Pi, however I am starting by creating minimal examples to get acquainted with GPIO and electrical stuff (I am a developer, not an electrical engineer).

Gathered from various examples across the internet I have done the following:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if not GPIO.input(11):
        print("Button pressed")
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

My circuit can be seen on the following screen:
[image: Circuit]

The resistor between blue and red is 10k Ohm, the one to the ground is 1k Ohm.

I start the program using `sudo python test.py`

I use standard raspbian (freshly flashed, everything updated)

Can somebody see what I am doing wrong?
The print statement is not issued if connect the green and red wire at the bottom manually.

Comment: Your code prints something if the two wires are NOT connected. To the Pi, 3V3 is a logic high and `GPIO.input()` will return `True`. `not True` evaluates to `False` and it doesn't print anything when pressed. But when it's not pressed, `GPIO.input()` returns `False`, and `not False` evaluates to `True` and it does print something. Remove the `not` and try again.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then here's the hardware troubleshooting list: Try connecting the blue wire directly to 3V3 to see if that triggers it. If it doesn't, then you have either: (1) Bad jumper wires/breakout/ribbon cable (2) Broken Pi. If you have a multimeter, check all your wires for continuity.

Comment: The circuit appears correct as far as can be told.   A common error is to connect the ribbon cable between the Pi and cobbler the wrong way around.

Comment: @joan: The brown cable on the left side of the ribbon is connected to the left side on the board (opposite of usb, towards the lcd connector)

Comment: @anonymoose can i safely connect just 3V3 and GPIO 17?

Comment: If you're nervous about that, put a 10K resistor in between them. That will protect it if it somehow gets configured as an output and set low.

Comment: @anonymoose thanks, it seems to be either the cable or the or the breakout.
I changed the code to check against GPIO.High and print high or low depending on the result. With cable and breakout connected it is always High. Connecting Pin 1 3V3 directly against 10k Ohm on the breadboard against Pin 40 (GPIO 21) switches from low to high if connect the cables